# How do I sort by a specific order

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Table users:

```
id | firstname | lastname
---+-----------+---------
 1 | John      | Smith
 2 | Adam      | Tensta
 3 | Anna      | Johansson
```

I want to select these in the order of ID 2, 3, 1. ONLY specified by the id-field. Is this possible?

I'm thinking something like `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ORDER(2,3,1)`

Can this be done, and in that case how?

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that the order you are trying to achieve is alphabetical by first name?  Or is there some other indicator in the data to give you the order you desire?  Sorting arbitrarily by ID seems odd.

Comment: It is just a coincidence, the idea is to sort based on the ID only. This can be for several reasons. For example user-specified order, ordered by another resultset on another layer in the application than the database etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Should work with a CASE in the order by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
ORDER BY case id when 2 then 1
                 when 3 then 2
                 when 1 then 3
         end
```

Comment: Nice solution. Just tested it on Oracle, not sure if it works with Postgres.

Comment: @Jules: should work in any database. That is ANSI compliant SQL

Answer (score 1):

### Generic solution for Postgres 9.4 or later

For any number of values. Just pass an array of matching type with your preferred sort order:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN unnest('{2,3,1}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY o(id, ord) USING (id)
ORDER  BY o.ord;
```

This sorts rows without match last because `ord` is NULL then and that sorts last in ascending order.

Similar solutions possible for older versions without `ORDINALITY`.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

#### Original answer for the given simple case

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY (id+1)%3
```

`%` is the [modulo operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html).

Comment: This is valid on this data set, but I want to be able to sort on any given order on the ID column. Interesting solution tho. :)

Comment: @Lilleman: I know the question is old, but when stumbling across it just now, I couldn't but add a generic solution.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks so much for editing this - the generic solution you added was just what I needed. :)