# Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, sql-order-by

I need to sort a PostgreSQL table ascending by a date/time field, e.g. `last_updated`.

But that field is allowed to be empty or null and I want records with null in `last_updated` come *before* non-null `last_updated`.
Is this possible?

```
order by last_updated asc  -- and null last_updated records first ??
```

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Postgres has the [**`NULLS FIRST | LAST`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) modifiers for `ORDER BY` expression:

```
... ORDER BY last_updated NULLS FIRST
```

The ***typical*** use case is with descending sort order (**`DESC`**), which produces the complete inversion of the default ascending order (**`ASC`**) with null values first - which is often not desirable. To sort `NULL` values last:

```
... ORDER BY last_updated DESC NULLS LAST
```

To support the query with an **index**, make it match:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON tbl (last_updated DESC NULLS LAST);
```

Postgres can read btree indexes backwards, so that's effectively  almost the same as just:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON tbl (last_updated);
```

For some query plans it matters where `NULL` values are appended. See:

- [Performance impact of view on aggregate function vs result set limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665508/performance-impact-of-view-on-aggregate-function-vs-result-set-limiting/69155660#69155660)

Comment: I did. That's how I got this page :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  SQLite3 added this feature and before using it, I wanted to make sure it was going to be compatible with PostgreSQL.  Turns out it's a standard thing these days!

Comment: Worth noting: `NULLS FIRST` is default for `DESC`, `NULLS LAST` is default for `ASC`.

Answer (score 21):

You can create a custom ORDER BY using a CASE statement.
The CASE statement checks for your condition and assigns to rows which meet that condition a lower value than that which is assigned to rows which do not meet the condition.
It's probably easiest to understand given an example:

```
  SELECT last_updated 
    FROM your_table 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN last_updated IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
         last_updated ASC;
```

Comment: Also, but you probably know this, `ASC` is the default sorting order so you do not necessarily need to type it.

Comment: `NULLS FIRST` is also the ANSI compliant way to write nulls first.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's useful in my case because I want to ignore the value if it's not null, and then sort by another column instead. (Im sorting notifications — unseen first (then `seenAt is null`), but if seen, then I sort by `createdAt` instaed)

Comment: Agreed; I found this useful when just wanting to sort by whether or not a value was present (in this case, a date) — and then sorting by another value secondarily. `NULLS FIRST` still sorted by the actual value if the value was non-null. This did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is the best solution. Can be used with anything else like for eg
`deleted_at >= xyz time` then 0 else 1 ...